# What would be the most effective way to have my automated vehicle's behavior change every time it reached a new waypoint? (Python)

Tags: python, if-statement

I would like to have my automated vehicle change its behavior every time it reaches a new waypoint. I planned to nest "if" statements for however many iterations I end up choosing, but the loop always gets stuck in the first if statement, keeping the vehicle in "aggressive" every time it reaches a new waypoint. What would be the best way to ensure the behavior changes everytime it reaches a new waypoint?

```
if agent.done():
    agent = BehaviorAgent(world.player, behavior='aggressive') 
    agent.set_destination(random.choice(spawn_points).location)
    world.hud.notification("The target has been reached, searching for another target", seconds=4.0)
    print("The target has been reached, searching for another target")

    if agent.done():
        agent = BehaviorAgent(world.player, behavior='cautious') 
        agent.set_destination(random.choice(spawn_points).location)
        world.hud.notification("The target has been reached, searching for another target", seconds=4.0)
        print("The target has been reached, searching for another target")
```

Comment: There is no loop in this code, so not sure how it can be getting stuck in one. Can you update with the rest of the code, and any errors/debugging output that shows it not working as expected?

Comment: Maybe the new agent that you assign on the second line is done, so the second `if` never succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that I completely misunderstood the question, but if I understood right, you want to change it every time a destination from aggressive to cautious and back to aggressive. I would do it with a global variable like this:

```
current_behavior = "cautious"

if agent.done():

    if current_behavior == "cautious":
        current_behavior = "aggressive"
        agent = BehaviorAgent(world.player, behavior='aggressive') 
        agent.set_destination(random.choice(spawn_points).location)
        world.hud.notification("The target has been reached, searching for another target", seconds=4.0)
        print("The target has been reached, searching for another target")

    elif current_behavior == "aggressive":
        current_behavior = "cautious"
        agent = BehaviorAgent(world.player, behavior='cautious') 
        agent.set_destination(random.choice(spawn_points).location)
        world.hud.notification("The target has been reached, searching for another target", seconds=4.0)
        print("The target has been reached, searching for another target")
```

And I would also clean up the unnecessary code like this:

```
current_behavior = "cautious"

if agent.done():

    if current_behavior == "cautious":
        agent = BehaviorAgent(world.player, behavior=current_behavior) 
        current_behavior = "aggressive"
    
    elif current_behavior == "aggressive":
        agent = BehaviorAgent(world.player, behavior=current_behavior)
        current_behavior = "cautious" 

    agent.set_destination(random.choice(spawn_points).location)
    world.hud.notification("The target has been reached, searching for another target", seconds=4.0)
    print("The target has been reached, searching for another target")
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you for your help!

Comment: Glad I could help! :)